# @ApiImplicitParams ... @Example(value) is ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am trying to provide custom JSON example to the body of my request.

I am writing

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(
                    paramType = "body",
                    //dataType = "com.  ...  .MyClass",
                    dataType = "java.lang.String",
                    name="payload",
                    examples = @Example(value = {
                            @ExampleProperty(value = "[\"haha\"]", mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    })
            )
    })
    public OperationResponse createEntity(@RequestBody MyClass payload ...
```

If `@ApiImplicitParams` annotation is absent, Swagger draws deserialization of `MyClass` which is incorrect. I am trying to provide predefined example (haha string). When I am adding `@ApiImplicitParams` only

```
string
```

appears in the body, hot haha.

Why and how to fix?